# Cannot pass array value from class containing main method to different classes

Tags: java

Our teacher asked us to create a program that would replicate the working of a stack based on the principle of LIFO and would also indicate stack overflow and empty stack.

I created three classes. Retrievee class containing main method which takes input from user using String[] args. Other class Push uses the values in Retrievee class Push should accept the values according to its size and checks if values exceeds size which it would and states overflow and proceeds to class Pop which uses the values in Class push rather then retrievee.

```
class Push extends Retrivee
{
  int i;
  Push()
  {
    String push[]= new String[10];
    //int push[]=new int[10];
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
      //Retrivee ele= new Retrivee();
      push[i]=a[i];
      System.out.print("value in Push["+i+"]="+push[i]);
      if( i == 9 )
         {
           System.out.print("Stack for push has Overflown");
         }
    }
  }
}

class Pop extends Push
{
  int i;
  Pop()
  {
    String pop[]= new String[10];
    //int pop[]= new int[10];
    for(i=10;i>=-1;i--)
    {
      //Push ele1= new Push();
      pop[i]=push[i];
      System.out.print("value in Pop["+i+"]="+pop[i]);
      if(i == -1)
      {
       System.out.print("Stack for pop is empty");
      }
    }
  }
}
public class Retrivee
{
    public static void main(String args[] )
    {
        System.out.println("please enter 12 elements");
        String a[] = new String[13];
        //int a[]=new int [13];
        a[1]=args[1];
        a[2]=args[2];
        a[3]=args[3];
        a[4]=args[4];
        a[5]=args[5];
        a[6]=args[6];
        a[7]=args[7];
        a[8]=args[8];
        a[9]=args[9];
        a[10]=args[10];
        a[11]=args[11];

    /*
        a[0]=Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
        a[1]=Integer.parseInt (args[1]);
        a[2]=Integer.parseInt (args[2]);
        a[3]=Integer.parseInt (args[3]);
        a[4]=Integer.parseInt (args[4]);
        a[5]=Integer.parseInt (args[5]);
        a[6]=Integer.parseInt (args[6]);
        a[7]=Integer.parseInt (args[7]);
        a[8]=Integer.parseInt (args[8]);
        a[9]=Integer.parseInt (args[9]);
        a[10]=Integer.parseInt (args[10]);
        a[11]=Integer.parseInt (args[11]);
     */

     /* Push push1 =new Push();
        Pop pop1 =new Pop();

     */
    }
}
```

at the time of compile i got the error

```
 Retrivee.java:11:error :cannot find symbol
    push[i]=a[i];
    symbol: variable a
    location:class Push
 Retrivee.java:31:error :cannot find symbol
    pop[i]=push[i];
    symbol: variable push
    location:class Pop
```

So I at last thought maybe values taken from String[] args cannot be passed to another classes. So improved the code little bit.

```
class Push //extends Retrive
{
    public Push()
    {
        int i;
        String push[]= new String[10];
        //Retrive ele= new Retrive();
        try
        {
            for(i=0;i<13;i++)
            {
                push[i]=Retrive.a[i];
                System.out.println("value in Push["+i+"]="+push[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack for push has Overflown");
        }
    }
}

class Pop //extends Push
{
    public Pop()
    {
        int j;
        String pop[]= new String[10];
        //Push ele1= new Push();
        try
        {
            for(j=9;j>=-1;j--)
            {
                pop[j]=Pop.push[j];
                System.out.println("value in Pop["+j+"]="+pop[j]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ev)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack for pop is empty");
        }
    }
}

public class Retrive 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a[] = new String[13];
        for(int k=0;k<13;k++)
        {
            int d[]=new int[13];
            d[k]=2*k;
            a[k]=Integer.toString(d[k]);
            System.out.println("a["+k+"]= "+a[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

but again ended up with same errors

```
 Retrive.java:12:error :cannot find symbol
    push[i]=Retrive.a[i];
    symbol: variable a
    location:class Retrive
 Retrive.java:34:error :cannot find symbol
    pop[i]=Pop.push[i];
    symbol: variable push
    location:class Pop
```

then I tried this code but in just single class that contained the main method.

```
public class Retrivee
{
    public static void main(String args[] )
    {
        String a[] = new String[13];
        for(int k=0;k<13;k++)
        {
            int d[]=new int[13];
            d[k]=2*k;
            a[k]=Integer.toString(d[k]);
            System.out.println("a["+k+"]= "+a[k]);
        }
        int i;
        String push[]= new String[10];
        try
        {
            for(i=0;i<13;i++)
            {
                push[i]=a[i];
                System.out.println("value in Push["+i+"]="+push[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack for push has Overflown");
        }
        int j;
        String pop[]= new String[10];
        try
        {
            for(j=9;j>=-1;j--)
            {
                pop[j]=push[j];
                System.out.println("value in Pop["+j+"]="+pop[j]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ev)
        {
            System.out.println("Stack for pop is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

and at last it worked.  Why did it not work in the above two cases? If it could have worked please tell how and where the changes should have been made.

The last thing I want to ask is why can't we set the size of String args[] in main method by writing like this

```
  public static void main(String args[] = new String[10]) 
  {
  }
```

and following the first example I wrote a small code

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyScan 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //String[] args = new String[10];
        String[] in = new String[4];//= {"1 a 10 . 100 1000","12","2112"};
        in[0]= "1"; //args[0];
        in[1]= "2"; //args[1];
        in[2]= "3"; //args[2];
        String accum;
        for(int x = 0; x <3; x++)   
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(in[x]);
            accum = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(accum);
        }
    }
}
```

when i wrote

```
 in[0]= args[0];
 in[1]= args[1];
 in[2]= args[2];
```

it threw

```
  Exception in thread"main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0
  at MyScan.main<MyScan.java:9>
```

but the above initialization worked when used in another program, but somewhat in a different way.

```
    String a= args[0];
    String b= args[1];
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I suggest that you step back and write *another* small program which illustrates the key issue. This is called an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Doing this will help you understand the problem more clearly and maybe even find a solution on your own. If you still have problems, going through this process makes your question more clear in your own mind so that you can write out your question here in a precise way and get the help you want more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking more than one question here, but...

`cannot find symbol` is the compiler's way of telling you that you have undefined references to some variable floating around.  It will even tell you which variables they are.  So, right now, you do not have `a` or `push` defined as anything.  Declare and instantiate them to their appropriate values.

You shouldn't need to set the size of `args[]`, since it's essentially unlimited.  `args[]` is used when passing parameters in on the command line:

```
java program1 param1 param2 param3 param4 ... param99
```

...and each one of these parameters will be in `args`.

You could write this for `main` and it would mean the same thing:

```
public static void main(String... args) { }
```

The above is known as [`varargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).  I'd advise you look into that reference.